# How To submit my time of win game in game center in ios

Tags: ios, game-center

how to post/Submit my time in game center in iOS  acutely i am complete my game with in **2** mint and Submit my time **game center**

**02.00** 
and acutely **leaderboard** save time like this  **0.00.02** 
i want submit my time look like in leaderboard **0.02.00**

[image]

```
currentScore=02.22;

[[GameCenterManager sharedManager] saveAndReportScore:currentScore leaderboard:leaderboardNameID
                                                    sortOrder:GameCenterSortOrderLowToHigh];
```

Comment: A wild guess: the server expects you to send the number of seconds, check the API docs to clear it out.

Comment: acceding to you  i am convert  my time  in number of seconds

Comment: Well then, maybe a look at your code would be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Don't add the code with new comments, edit the question instead. Add more related code, the single assignment operation is hardly useful to understand the whole process that you have created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `score` parameter is an integer, so you should be tracking the number of seconds as the score, not the number of minutes:

```
int score = 2 * 60 + 22;   // 142 seconds = 2m22s
```

[Reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GameCenterManager/5.3/Classes/GameCenterManager.html#//api/name/saveAndReportScore:leaderboard:sortOrder:)